# Plot does not scale correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, horizontal-alignment

I'm having a hard time trying to center a simple `pgfplots`.

This is my code:

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{ Comparação da função tangente hiperbólica em diferentes implementações.}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \fonte{Próprio autor.}
    \label{fig:tanh-plot}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=3, connect spies}]
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$ x $},
            ylabel={$ y = \tanh{x} $},
            xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
            ymin=-1.0, ymax=1.0,
            legend pos=north west,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
        ]

            \addplot[color=orange, mark=*,]
                table {plots/tanh-tf.dat};
                \addlegendentry{Keras/TensorFlow (Python)}

            \addplot[color=blue, mark=*,]
                table {plots/tanh-vhdl.dat};
                \addlegendentry{Interpolação (VHDL)}

            \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:-.75, -.63);
            %\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:0, 0);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:2, -.2);

        \end{axis}

        \spy[blue, size=8cm] on (spypoint) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives me the following result (I only cropped the bottom part of the page):

[image: Buggy plot :(]

How do I center the plot? It seems to have space in the left margin to do so, so why doesn't it?

Comment: The text "Próprio autor." and the plot are on the same line in the same paragraph.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I guess that was it (?) -- see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I had to do was place this section:

```
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\fonte{Próprio autor.}
\label{fig:tanh-plot}
```

after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

I think I also need some sleep as well.

The result now:
[image: fixed, pretty plot]